# Carmen Robotics

Tags: robotics, carmen

I have been working with Carmen http://carmen.sourceforge.net/ for a while now, and I really like the software but I need to make some changes inside the source code.

I am therefore interesting in some students reports/projects there have been working with Carmen, or any documentation of the source code.

I have been reading the documentation on the webpage for Carmen, but with all respect I think the literature there is a bit outdated and insufficient.

Comment: I suppose you're talking about http://carmen.sourceforge.net/? It would be useful to specify this in your question

Comment: Yes I'am talking about http://carmen.sourceforge.net/ - thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the changes you need? Or perhaps split this question into several specific questions?

Comment: I cannot be the only person working with Carmen, so there must be others who also has worked with Carmen either students who have created a project where they have to change in Carmen or create a detailed description of how each module works by Carmen. I am especially interested in how Mapping and Navigation module works either in the form of student reports or other documentation.

Answer (score 3):

ROS is the new hot navigation toolkit for robotics. It has a professional development group and a very active community. The documentation is okay, but it's the best I've seen for robotic operating systems.

There are a lot of student project teams that are using it.

Check it out at www.ros.org

I'll be more specific on why ROS is awesome...

Built in visualizer/simulator rviz
 - It has a record function which will record all of the messages passed out of nodes, this allows you take in a lot of raw data store it in a "ros bag" and then play it back later when you need to test your AI, but want to sit in your bed.

Built in navigation capabilities,

-all you have to do is write the publishers of data for your sensors. 
 -It has standard messages that you need to fill out so that the stack has enough information.

There is an Extended Kalman Filter which is pretty awesome because I didn't want to write one. Currently implementing it, i'll let you know how that turns out.

It also has built in message levels, by that I mean you can change which severity of print messages are printed during runtime, fairly handy for debugging.

There's a robot monitor node that you can publish the status of your sensors to and it bundles all of that information into a GUI for your viewing pleasure.

There are some basic drivers already written. For example SICK lidars are supported right out of the box.

There is also a built in transform function, to help you move everything to the right coordinate system.

ROS was made to run across multiple computers, but can work on just one.

Data transfer is handled over TCP ports.

I hope that's more helpful.

Comment: Anyone who uses the words/phrases "hot new", "professional", "very active community" and "best I've seen" in a one paragraph description of a project needs to explain their affiliation with said project ...

Comment: ahaha, sorry I just love it. I'm not in any way affiliated with it. I just use it.

Comment: Player/Stage does this and is a bit more complete.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I am only interested in Carmen.